# How to know user buy any product from amazon?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I am a seller on amazon.com.

I receive buyer's email from the MWS Amazon API and I want to send email to buyers.

Are there any API or webhooks for this?

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative solution you could set up an autoresponder for these mails or if you want to add specific information you could pull the mails with a script from the mailserver, parse them and respond them in the way you like.

Not sure if there are ways to do this directly with the Amazon API. Shouldn´t you as "Amazon Senior Technical Trainer" know that best? At least it is documented: https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/docs.html/168-5625022-9334311